# Boost BiMap Parse Template Error

Tags: c++11, templates, boost, bimap

I am getting parse template error when I add `#include<boost/bimap.hpp>`
I want to find the key of a map from its value and hence thought of using Boost's Bimap but getting below error.

```
/usr/include/boost/bimap/relation/structured_pair.hpp: In function ‘bool boost::bimaps::relation::operator<(const boost::bimaps::relation::structured_pair<FirstType, SecondType, Info, Layout1>&, const boost::bimaps::relation::structured_pair<FirstType, SecondType, Info, Layout2>&)’:
/usr/include/boost/bimap/relation/structured_pair.hpp:375:19: error: parse error in template argument list
     return (  ( a.first  <  b.first  ) ||
                   ^
/usr/include/boost/bimap/relation/structured_pair.hpp: In function ‘bool boost::bimaps::relation::operator<=(const boost::bimaps::relation::structured_pair<FirstType, SecondType, Info, Layout1>&, const boost::bimaps::relation::structured_pair<FirstType, SecondType, Info, Layout2>&)’:
/usr/include/boost/bimap/relation/structured_pair.hpp:383:19: error: parse error in template argument list
     return (  ( a.first  <  b.first  ) ||
                   ^
/usr/include/boost/bimap/relation/structured_pair.hpp: In function ‘bool boost::bimaps::relation::operator<(const boost::bimaps::relation::structured_pair<FirstType, SecondType, Info, Layout1>&, const std::pair<F, S>&)’:
/usr/include/boost/bimap/relation/structured_pair.hpp:424:19: error: parse error in template argument list
     return (  ( a.first  <  b.first  ) ||
                   ^
/usr/include/boost/bimap/relation/structured_pair.hpp: In function ‘bool boost::bimaps::relation::operator<=(const boost::bimaps::relation::structured_pair<FirstType, SecondType, Info, Layout1>&, const std::pair<F, S>&)’:
/usr/include/boost/bimap/relation/structured_pair.hpp:432:19: error: parse error in template argument list
     return (  ( a.first  <  b.first  ) ||
                   ^
/usr/include/boost/bimap/relation/structured_pair.hpp: In function ‘bool boost::bimaps::relation::operator<(const std::pair<F, S>&, const boost::bimaps::relation::structured_pair<FirstType, SecondType, Info, Layout1>&)’:
/usr/include/boost/bimap/relation/structured_pair.hpp:473:19: error: parse error in template argument list
     return (  ( a.first  <  b.first  ) ||
                   ^
/usr/include/boost/bimap/relation/structured_pair.hpp: In function ‘bool boost::bimaps::relation::operator<=(const std::pair<F, S>&, const boost::bimaps::relation::structured_pair<FirstType, SecondType, Info, Layout1>&)’:
/usr/include/boost/bimap/relation/structured_pair.hpp:481:19: error: parse error in template argument list
     return (  ( a.first  <  b.first  ) ||
```

Comment: Please show the minimal code to reproduce. If it's **just** the include, name compiler and versions

Comment: From what you've shown here I suspect a #define overrides the meaning of an identifier involved (e.g. like `first`) making the compiler think a template argument list is coming with the `<`

Comment: Sorry.. I have not written any code yet. If i just include the header, i am getting the error. 
Compiler is - gcc 4.8.5

Comment: Other versions (boost?) and flags?

Answer (score 0):

Using GCC 4.8.5:

- boost 1.64 https://wandbox.org/permlink/kg4tkbEIdHMv4mII
- boost 1.60 https://wandbox.org/permlink/1lA2L194rNfZrFsd
- boost 1.54 https://wandbox.org/permlink/7RUl49NAy0q9D2u3
- boost 1.49 https://wandbox.org/permlink/kpILpo63riVQGVyP

So all in all it looks like you're doing something else wrong. What other includes are there? Check the preprocessed source if possible.